# How to read File with my WebApi Custom MediaTypeFormatter

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv, asp.net-web-api, mediatypeformatter

i'm creating a ASP.NET MVC WEBAPI application where i'm actually implementing  a Custom MediaTypeFormatter to deal with some type of contents. (csv for example)

My goal is Read a file posted from a form in my webbrowser. But the read method of my mediatypeformatter is never reached.

Does anyone have a working example of MediaTypeFormatters, where a posted file is readed?

Or can some one point a direction?

FORM:
    <form action="/API/controller/sendfile" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

i'm getting this error: No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'IEnumerable`1' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-part has multiple parts. So, you need to read them, like so:

```
public async Task Post()
{
    var multipart = await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();

    foreach (var content in multipart.Contents)
    {
        var products = await content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Product>>();
    }
}
```

`ReadAsAsync<T>` can read the request based on the media formatters you have - both out of box and custom. So, in your case, if you have the formatter for CSV configured, depending on the MIME type of the file, it should read the request content correctly.